# Why did US Navy sailors apologize for swearing, even in front of C.O.?

Tags: realism, greyhound

USN sailors apologizing for swearing, accurate? Why apologize? Don't sailors cuss?

USN sailor said "Son of a bitch ricocheted off the surface" in front of Commander Ernest Krause. Then sailor says "My language, sir".

Another sailor said "Fuck". Then "Sorry my language sir". In both cases Krause doesn't respond their apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why apologize? Don't sailors cuss?

Of course they curse...but it's still not something one does in front of a superior while on duty.

However, in this case, the captain is seen to be a deeply religious person and so swearing in front of him is even more of an "offence" that the sailor might feel impelled to apologize for.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i can't remember which, but other war movies show juniors cussing in front superiors. but i forgot "the captain is seen to be a deeply religious person". thanks.